# This transaction cannot be processed due to an unsupported currency - Paypal direct payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on a website where paypal is used as the payment medium. While I transfer funds using "Paypal express checkout" and "Paypal Direct Payment" , in first case,

1. Paypal express checkout - I am getting a response message as "Pending" and error as "multicurrency"
2. Paypal Direct Payment - using credit card, I am getting a message as "This transaction cannot be processed due to an unsupported currency"

I am using Sandbox and as a user charging 99.00 SEK (Swedish Krona). 
When I use US $ it is working fine. So I assume this is due to currency. 
But I would like to know how can I make it working on SEK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem... I think it have something to do with setting merchant account: [PayPal is returning error on currency 10755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451408/paypal-is-returning-error-on-currency-10755)